# quarkus native ldap call

Tags: ldap, quarkus

In our quarkus app we use a LDAP server to retrieve user data. The code in a nutshell looks like this:

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "5000");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=" + ldapUser + "," + ldapOrganization);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPw);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapServer);
new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

With the jre version it all runs well, but with quarkus native I get ClassNotFoundExceptions. Build and startup are successful, but calling the app doesn't work.

At first I got a
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`
but I could get rid of it by including the quarkus-elytron-security-ldap extension and disabling it by `quarkus.security.ldap.enabled=false`.

Now the exception is
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`. I wonder how the quarkus-elytron-security-ldap extension talks to the ldap server without that error.

I'm using quarkus 1.13.7.Final, mvn 3.6.3 and azul jdk 11.0.10 on ubuntu 20.04.

What I discovered so far:

- I did include a truststore as explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl#the-truststore-path and other https calls to rest servers do work with it.
- The solution from [Quarkus LDAP get user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916126/quarkus-ldap-get-user-data) would work on my machine, but it needs to work for developers on win machines as well.
- https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2808 sounds like SSLSocketFactory is and will not be part of GraalVM, but then how does the quarkus-elytron-security-ldap extension talk to the ldap server?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem today.
Seems that JNDI isnt active by default.

Use this setting

```
quarkus.naming.enable-jndi=true
```

to enable JNDI in Quarkus apps.

Comment: Good to hear I m not the only one with this approach. Back in the quarkus 1.13 days jndi was enabled by default, but there s a lot more that changed since then. Did you manage to get it working with a newer version?

Comment: Yea, running Quarkus 2.9.2 and able to connect to and query our LDAP server without issues. Running on the JVM though and not compiled to native.